# Stereographic projection piecewise smooth at North Pole

Tags: stereographic-projections

Let
$$ \varphi:\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^2-{N} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$$
be the (inverse) stereographic projection from the North pole on the unit sphere centred at the origin.

$$\varphi(x,y) =  \left( \frac{2x}{x^2+y^2+1},\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2+1},\frac{x^2+y^2-1} {x^2+y^2+1} \right)
$$
Let
$$\hat{f}(x,y) = (\alpha x, \alpha y)
$$
where $\alpha >0. $
$$f: \mathbb{S}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^2 = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll}
      \varphi \circ \hat{f} \circ \varphi^{-1} & on \quad \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^2-{N} \\
      f(N)=N & \\
\end{array} 
\right. 
$$

How would I show that the map is smooth at $N$ and compute $Df|_N$ at the north pole?

In the Jacobian representation, $Df|_N$ goes to infinity.

I tried taking
$$\lim_{\epsilon=(a,b,c)\rightarrow (0,0,0)} \frac{f(N+\epsilon)-f(N)}{\epsilon} 
$$
But the same problem happens.

Is there a reformulation of $f$, say $h$ which is equal to $f$ but expressed entirely differently (for example in polar coordinates?)

Any hints or clues are appreciated!

Comment: Your $f$ is the identity, so the derivative is the identity at any point. You need a chart around the north pole, e.g. stereographic projection from the south pole, to compute the derivative in the chart representation.

Comment: Sorry I've missed a piece out - just editing it in now

Comment: Okay. The second part of my comment still applies. You need a chart around $N$ and express $f$ in that chart.

Comment: So something like -(φS o fhat o φS^-1) around and including N

Comment: More something like $\varphi_S^{-1}\circ f \circ \varphi_S$. You want a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ to compute the derivative.

Comment: I'm gonna try and compute that now - thanks for the great explanation

Comment: Ok I get the Matrix
$\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}$
ie the plane parallel to xy at the north pole (which sounds right geometrically!)

Comment: There should appear an $\alpha$ somewhere. It should be of the form $$g(\alpha)\cdot\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$ where I don't know $g(\alpha)$ without computing, but it should be similar to $\frac{1}{\alpha}$.

Comment: By the way I'm really sorry to take so much of your time!

Comment: You're not "taking" it. It's my own decision. If I wanted to, I could just ignore any comments here or turn off the computer or whatever.

Comment: Point taken, still grateful :) I think I know what I did wrong; when I use $g=\varphi_{S}^{-1} \circ f \circ \varphi_{S}$ and compute $Dg = D\varphi_{S}^{-1} \circ Df \circ D\varphi_{S}$ I get that $Df|_{N} = I_{3 \times 3}$ ie the identity. I shouldn't be using that should I? It's more fruitful to use $f = \varphi_{N} \circ \hat{f} \circ \varphi_{N}^{-1}$ right?

Comment: The sphere is two-dimensional. It doesn't make sense to say $Df\lvert_N$ is a $3\times 3$-matrix. You can only express $Df\lvert_N$ as a matrix if you have a basis of the tangent space. Typically, you get that via a coordinate chart. Here, the stereographic projection from the south pole is a natural coordinate chart around the north pole. Then you express $Df\lvert_N$ in that chart, as $Dg\lvert_0$.

Comment: That seems to be where my understanding falls short; how would you express $Df|_{N}$ as $Dg|_{0}$; I just can't grasp how to rewrite f in the chart as g - is there a formula I should be using? :(

Comment: $g = (\varphi_S^{-1}\circ\varphi) \circ \hat{f} \circ (\varphi^{-1}\circ \varphi_S)$. Compute $\varphi^{-1}\circ \varphi_S$ and its inverse, and you have an explicit representation of $g$. Computing the derivative of $g$ is standard. Then you have the representation of $Df\lvert_N$ _in the chart_ $\varphi_S$. Since it happens to be a multiple of the identity, the representation is the same in all charts, but that's coincidental, generally the representation of the derivative is chart-dependent.